# Чтение файла по частично известному имени

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Задача состоит в том чтобы открыть файл зная только часть имени. Файлы - экселевские таблички генерируемые автоматически, после названия идут дата и время, каждый раз уникальные: file_name_123456789. Нужна возможность открывать файл зная только начальную часть file_name.

Пробовал использовать регулярные выражения - вылезают ошибки.

```
data = pandas.read_excel('file_name\S*')
```

На такой код вылезает ошибка: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file_name\S*'

Использование шаблона тоже не помогает:

```
pattern = re.compile('\S*')
data = pandas.read_excel('file_name{}'.format(pattern))
```

Ошибка: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "file_namere.compile('\\S*')"

Каким образом это можно реализовать? Возможно я как то не так использую регулярные выражения?

Среда - PyCharm.

Comment: Используйте `glob`, а потом уже проверяйте на валидность (если надо). Типа `files = glob.glob("*file_name*")`

Comment: Да, действительно, с помощью glob выцепляю названия всех имеющихся файлов, и дальше с этими названиями уже можно легко работать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Pandas позволяет напрямую работать с объектами-путями из стандартного (для Python 3.x) модуля [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"/path/to/data/files")

for f in path.glob("file_name*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    # здесь работает с фреймом ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Используте [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```py
import glob
```

Найдите все файлы, содержащие в имени `file_name`:

```py
fldr = r'ПУТЬ_К_ФАЙЛАМ'
files = glob.glob(fr"{fldr}/file_name*")
```

Если нужно, добавьте условия, если нужно, даже с использованием регулярных выражений, например, если после `file_name` должен быть символ `_`, за которым должна следовать цифра:

```py
import re
files = glob.glob(fr"{fldr}/file_name*")
files = [f for f in files if re.search(r'^file_name_\d', os.path.basename(f))]
```